# C# - Protocol buffers "proto3" - how to generate Kestrel Web Server REST, or JSON-RPC methods from .proto file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, protocol-buffers, grpc

I use gRPC in my applications. New client needs both Servers: `grpc` and `rest-api`, I'd like to ask you, is there any tool that will help me to generate (for example) Kestrel, or maybe Nancy classes and methods to easly create `Rest` / `Json-RPC` API Server with exactly the same methods to override like in `grpc` ? Or have i do it manualy?

I checked Google, but i think that SEO tricks unabled me to find something like this, because every article i found redirecting me to `DI` gRPC to MVC apps.

Comment: hmmm; with the tooling that you're using, what would a typical Rest / Json-RPC endpoint look like? so that we can compare and contrast; in particular, I'm thinking: protobuf-net.Grpc makes endpoints look just like regular services (it doesn't use the normal gRPC base class/override approach) - you just have regular methods on the service; so it is *possible* that you could just register the same service type? there is tooling to emit the service definitions as interfaces, etc

Comment: @MarcGravell so, id does not matter how it looks like. I mean, it could be end.point/method_name and parameters in body, or end.point and method_name, and parameters in body. It really does not matter. 
Virtuals generated by protobuf needs generally grpc types of requests, and big problem i see with streams. its type f.e. ```  Grpc.Core.AsyncClientStreamingCall```

Comment: yeah, this will only really work for "unary" calls, but: the point I'm trying to make is that protobuf-net.Grpc *doesn't give you* an API that involves Grpc.Core etc; here's an example of "greeter service": https://github.com/neshcodes/grpc_xam_test/blob/master/GrpcApp.Server/Services/GreeterService.cs

Comment: hmm it looks wisely. But as i saw in envoy, and other "http2->http1 proxies" (its quoted because i don't believe it works as it should) you can see that working with streams is impossible. My idea was to create some kind of "converter" that makes grpc calls => json-rpc calls / rest calls , and grpc_stream => websocket message